# Java webstart issues with Java 7u65 "Could not find main-class..."

Tags: java, deployment, java-web-start

After updating java to 7u65 (from 7u60) one of our java web start applications will not launch.

The error I get is 'Could not find main-class ... in jar'

I read through the release notes and bug fixes for 7u65 in addition to searching on SO to find any information. I have not found any documentation that would explain why this worked fine in 7u60 but not 7u65

[image: WebStart error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. solutions:

- Move the jar which contains main class on top, or
- add main="true" for the jar which contains main class

Comment: I am having the same issue with an app client in an EAR deployed to Glassfish. It works fine outside the EAR. Where do I add main="true"?

Answer (score 1):

Our main method was packaged in our common jar, not the main jar as listed in the jnlp. 
The way we fixed this was to move the class containing the main method into the main jar listed in the jnlp. Although this seems obvious, the way we had it before worked in 7u60 and older.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Deleting `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java` resoved it.